# Find Coordinates between two points using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns Column X and Column Y. (X1,Y1) = (1,2) and (X2,Y2)= (9,10). Considering X1,Y1 as start Point and X2,Y2 as End Points, I can find Slope. But using slope and these points. How do I find remaining points between them

For Example: I have Values like

```
ColumnX  ColumnY
1         1
.         .
.         .
.         .
10        10
```

Slope is Y1-Y2/X1-X2 That is 10-1/10-1 =1

Using slope and the coordinates, How to find the remaining 9 coordinates between them using Sql

Comment: Hi Shika! Are you only looking for integer pairs that fall on the line?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're expecting?

Comment: If you have two points, and you want to find points between them (with integer coordiantes), then there is no need to know the slope, unless there is something I missed ?

Comment: Will the slope always be an integer? It's a somewhat different problem if the slope might be 1/2 or some other rational value and you only want points with integer coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what your input data looks like, but you can generate points using a recursive CTE:

```
with points as (
      select 1 as x_start, 2 as y_start, 9 as x_end, 10 as y_end
     ),
     cte as (
      select x_start as x, convert(float(53), y_start) as y, 9 as x_end, convert(float(53), (y_end - y_start) * 1.0 / (x_end - x_start)) as slope
      from points
      union all
      select x + 1, y + slope, x_end, slope
      from cte
      where x < x_end
     )
select *
from cte
order by x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a410fa7f8bf4aea0a784065c5621b90e) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=303b730f26edd23c31d0e379316c5043), let me know if it works for you

```
declare @x1 as decimal(10,2)
declare @y1 as decimal(10,2)
declare @x2 as decimal(10,2)
declare @y2 as decimal(10,2)

set @x1=1
set @y1=1
set @x2=10
set @y2=10


declare @mytab as table (x decimal(10,2),y decimal(10,2))

insert into @mytab values(@x1,@y1),(@x2,@y2)




declare @slope as decimal(10,2)
set @slope=(@y1-@y2)/(@x1-@x2)

--(y2=y1+s*(x2-x1)
;with cte as(
select @x1 x, @y1 y 
union all
select cast(x+1 as decimal(10,2)),cast( @y1+@slope*(x+1.0-@x1) as decimal(10,2)) from cte
where x+1 < 11)
select x,y from cte
```